# consultar todas las tablas de un esquema que tengan el mismo valor en una columna X

Tags: sql, oracle

Con la siguente query:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE column_name ='PR_CON_ID'
ORDER BY table_name
```

obtuve todas las tablas con la columna PR_CON_ID.

Ahora necesito acortar mas el resultado de la consulta y de esas tablas obtener solo las que tienen el mismo valor en la columna PR_CON_ID

Como quedaria la query para lograr eso?

Comment: añade una clausula where mas... para eso es la ayuda ??